# Where do I insert my file location into this code?

Tags: java, string, file

I have this code that reads a file and returns the content as String but I don not know where to put the file path or location

```
C:\Users\johnm\eclipse-workspace\W4A6\src\input.in
```

Any help would be great.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Encryption {

    public static String readFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        String content = "";
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            content += scanner.nextLine();
        }
        return content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So far, you have only defined a method that reads a file with a given filename.
You need to call it using the file path you wish, so in your case:

```
String content = Encryption.readFile("C:\\Users\\johnm\\eclipse-workspace\\W4A6\\src\\input.in");
```

Comment: This only matters if the OP is hard-coding a [string literal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-initialization-java-string-literal-vs-string-object/), and only if the string literal happens to include Windows "\" delimiters.  If the program accepts the pathname from user input (e.g. a command line, or a text widget): no problem.  If the path uses forward slash delimiters ("/") - no problem.  FUN FACT: Most file I/O functions will accept *EITHER* forward-slash or back-slash path delimiters on Windows - it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Q:  Where do I put the file path or location?

A: Whoever calls the `readFile()` method of your `Encryption` class will determine the file path name.

One common technique is a "[static main](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-static-in-public-static-void-main-in-java/)", and pass the filepath as a command line parameter.

EXAMPLE:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Encryption {

    public static String readFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        String content = "";
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            content += scanner.nextLine();
        }
        return content;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a filepath");
        } else {
            Encryption.readFile(args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you might invoke Encryption.readFile() from a GUI.  Or from a web service.

Regardless: the caller should always "know" the filepath, and pass it as an argument to readFile().